# send model to MVC C# controller´s action via button click event jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I,ve been working on a MVC C# project and I need to send the info (model) from my View to the due controller action but after managing some validations via jQuery and the click event of the submit button, here is the javascript code on click of submit button and its validation (works fine)

```
 $("#sentInfo").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#idProveedor").val(proveedor);
            $("#idacme").val('ingresar');

                var table = $('#myTable');

                table.find('tbody tr').each(function (index, tr) {
                    if ($(tr).find("td:eq(2)").html() === $("#idDUI").val()) {
                        alert('ya existe el DUI');
                        exit;
                    }

                    else if ($(tr).find("td:eq(3)").html() === $("#idISSS").val()) {
                        alert('ya existe el ISSS');
                        exit;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("form").submit();
                    }
                });
        });
```

the code above sets the values to the #idProveedor and #idacme inputs and also validate if the DUI or ISSS already exists but if the values already exist it always send the model to the action and what I want that if ISSS or DUI values exists then the model shouldn't be send to the action method.
Can anyone help me?

this is my form code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarEALG", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id = "FormEmp" }))
            {
...
some code goes here
...
<input type="submit" value="Ingresar Empleado" class="btn btn-info" id="sentInfo" />
}
```

this is the code with modifications:

```
  $("#sentInfo").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#idProveedor").val(proveedor);
            $("#idacme").val('ingresar');

             var table = $('#myTable');

                table.find('tbody tr').each(function (index, tr) {
                    if ($(tr).find("td:eq(2)").html() === $("#idDUI").val()) {
                        alert('ya existe el DUI');
                        exit;
                    }

                    else if ($(tr).find("td:eq(3)").html() === $("#idISSS").val()) {
                        alert('ya existe el ISSS');
                        exit;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("FormEmp").submit();
                    }
                });
        });
```

and the button

```
<input type="button" value="Ingresar Empleado" class="btn btn-info" id="sentInfo" />
```

Comment: yes, all the properties of the model :   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.property)

Comment: change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. because it is a `submit` type it will automatically post-back for you, make it a `button` to allow javascript to handle the submit.

Comment: thanks, and once changed the type how to send the model, might be: $("form").submit ?  another question, I use e.preventdefault, doesn't help in the case to use input=submit for yhe button?

Comment: Your `.each()` loop means that if any row in your table does not meet those conditions then the form will be submitted. I assume you want to prevent the submit if any row is 'invalid'?

Comment: yep, `$("form").submit();` or `$("#FormEmp").submit();` if you have more than one form. I think the javascript code you have will work.

Comment: @DaveBecker, That is bad practice. You should always handle the `.submit()` event and cancel the default action as OP is doing.

Comment: @DaveBecker how should I do it?

Comment: @DaveBecker I just edit the question to show how script code that handle the click event of the button, now it doesn't send the form if the validations fail but in case the validations success(DUI and ISSS don´t exists) it doesn´t send the model to the controller, in your experience, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @PabloMayora to be honest, I am very concerned that I am giving you bad advice according to @StephenMuecke. Maybe he'll post an answer and show us all how to do it properly. FWIW try `$("#FormEmp").submit();` (you missed the `#`)

Comment: @PabloMayora instead of  `$("#sentInfo").click(function (e) {})` try  `$("form").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use ajax to send your data from your view to your controller. I use this often and might be a good solution for you since you are using a jQuery click event. Below is an untested example but it will give you an idea of how to do it.

```
function Save(model){

    var data = {
      'modelNameToPass': model
    }

    $.ajax({
         url: "/Home/EnviarEALG", // "/ControllerName/Method"
         data: data,
         type: "POST",
         success: function(response){
             //code to do something on success
         },
         error: function(response){
            //do error stuff here
         }
    });

}
```

Then your controller should already be set up like this..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EnviarEALG(DataModel modelNameToPass)
{

}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: although that's an excellent solution, in my case is not an option, not because of me but for my peers, so I have to stick to the old MVC, thanks anyway.